# will wine marinade kill bacteria?

Tags: wine, marinade

After grocery shopping, my husband left vacuum sealed 2 jars of wine marinades herring outside the fridge on a shelf for 2 days.  The shelf is in a cool spot. Can we still eat it?  I have put them back into the fridge.

Comment: Were they previously opened? Were they in a refrigeration section when you bought them? Does the jar say "keep refrigerated" or "refrigerate after opening"? If they were homemade I'd say definitely not, but if they came off a grocery shelf then they might have been pasteurized, and/or the wine marinade may have been treated with citric acid or another acidifier.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [How long is it safe to marinate meat?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1511) and [Is acid-marinated raw chicken still safe after several days?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12945) and the OP has never followed up, making this too vague (not to mention dangerous) to answer properly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of bacteria aren't killed by wine or any acid marinade.
Anyway, if jars were sealed and content pasteurized they probably didn't grow any bacteria meanwhile. You can consider cooking it if you're unsure.

Comment: If you're unsure about bad bacteria...you *don't* cook it, you throw it out.